Ghub buggy on g600?
I recently discovered the world of lua and I'm testing simple macros to improve the language. When I discovered that GHUB uses lua to make scripts, I tried to do something simple to hold recoil in any game
EnableRCS = true -- Quando definido como false, desativa o controle de recuo.

RecoilControlMode = "High" -- Predefinições: "Low", "Medium", "High", "Ultra", "Insanity", "Custom"

RcCustomStrength = 7 -- O valor DEVE ser ARREDONDADO! Sem valores decimais como 6.5!

RequireToggle = true -- Mude para false se você quiser que ele esteja sempre ativado.

ToggleKey = "CapsLock" -- Teclas utilizáveis: "CapsLock", "NumLock", "ScrollLock"

DelayRate = 7 -- NÃO ALTERE SE VOCÊ NÃO SABE O QUE ESTÁ FAZENDO.

-- Predefinições de Recuo --
if RecoilControlMode == "Low" then
    RecoilControlStrength = 8
elseif RecoilControlMode == "Medium" then
    RecoilControlStrength = 10
elseif RecoilControlMode == "High" then
    RecoilControlStrength = 14
end
-- Predefinições de Recuo --

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: %s, Arg: %d\n", event, arg) -- Adiciona depuração
    if EnableRCS then
        if RequireToggle then
            if IsKeyLockOn(ToggleKey) then
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then -- Botão direito do mouse
                    repeat
                        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then -- Botão esquerdo do mouse
                            repeat
                                MoveMouseRelative(0, RecoilControlStrength)
                                Sleep(DelayRate)
                            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                        end
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
                end
            end
        else
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then -- Botão direito do mouse
                repeat
                    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then -- Botão esquerdo do mouse
                        repeat
                            MoveMouseRelative(0, RecoilControlStrength)
                            Sleep(DelayRate)
                        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                    end
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
            end
        end
    end
end

OutputLogMessage("Script Loaded\n")


The Script works perfectly apart from a single detail, for it to be active, in addition to the left and right click being pressed, I need to hold the g9 (side button of the g600)... with some simple debugging codes and help from the documentation provided by logitech, I couldn't find anything to solve this bug
With capslock on and pressing the left and right buttons, the cursor would go down, but for that to happen I need to hold down the g9 on my mouse
